# how to get appended value in a systematic way using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

```
<div id="unique">

   <div class="form-group">

         <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select name="cname" class="form-control" id="coid<?php echo $c;?>" fd="0" onChange="countryfunction(this);" required>
                    <option >choose country</option>
                      <?php
                        include('include/db.php');
                        $sql="select id,country_name from country";
                        $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("error");
                              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_BOTH))
                              {                               
                              ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $country_id=$row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></option>

                          <?php } ?></select>
                      <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
             </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">State Name</label>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                              <select name="state" class="form-control" id="sid<?php echo $c;?>" md="0" onChange="statefunction(this);" >
                              <option >Select state</option>
                              </select>
                             <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">City Name</label>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <select name="city" class="form-control" id="cid<?php echo $c;?>" >
                              <option >Select City</option>
                              </select>
                          <span class="help-block"></span>
                     </div>
                 </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" value="+" onClick="add_function()" id="btnid<?php echo $i;?>" />
                      <span class="help-block"></span>
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

```
function countryfunction(see) {
var nnn=$(see).attr('fd');
var DATA = document.getElementById("coid"+nnn).value;
var sid = document.getElementById("sid"+nnn);
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {  
 sid.innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
};
  xhttp.open("GET", "stateid1.php?r="+DATA, true);
  xhttp.send();  
}
function statefunction(dee) {
var mmm=$(dee).attr('md');
var data = document.getElementById("sid"+mmm).value;
var Y = document.getElementById("cid"+mmm);
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {  
 Y.innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
};
  xhttp.open("GET", "cityidr.php?r="+data, true);
  xhttp.send();
 }


var i=0;
var c=0;

          function add_function() {
                   var objTo = document.getElementById('unique')
                   var divtest = document.createElement('unique');
i++;
c++;
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt =" ";
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    txt += "<div class='form-group' > <label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Country Name</label><div class='col-md-6'><select name='country[]' onChange='countryfunction(this);' fd='"+c+"' id='coid"+c+"' class='form-control'><option>--Choose Country--</option>"
    for (x in myObj) {
     txt += "<option value='"+myObj[x].id+"'>" + myObj[x].country_name;

}   
         txt += "</select><span class='help-block'></span></div></div>"
        divtest.innerHTML+= txt
}
}
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "demo6.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);

       var obj1, dbParam1, xmlhttp1, myObj1, y, txt1 = "";
      dbParam1= JSON.stringify(obj1);
      xmlhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                   myObj1 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                   txt1 += "<div class='form-group' ><label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>State Name</label><div class='col-md-6'><select name='state[]' onChange='statefunction(this);' md='"+c+"' id='sid"+c+"' class='form-control'><option>--Select state--</option>"
   for (y in myObj1) {
     txt1 += "<option value='"+myObj1[y].id+"'>" + myObj1[y].state_name;
   }
     txt1 +="</select><span class='help-block'></span></div></div>"
     divtest.innerHTML+= txt1   
   }
   }    
      xmlhttp1.open("POST", "demo9.php", true);
      xmlhttp1.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp1.send("y=" + dbParam1);
        var obj3, dbParam3, xmlhttp3, myObj3, z, txt3 = "";
    dbParam3 = JSON.stringify(obj3);
    xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             myObj3 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
             txt3 += "<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>City Name</label><div class='col-md-6'><select name='city[]' id='cid"+c+"' class='form-control'><option>--Select City--</option>"
    for (z in myObj3) {
        txt3 += "<option value='"+myObj3[z].id+"'>" + myObj3[z].city_name;
    }
    txt3 += "</select><span class='help-block'></span></div></div>"
   divtest.innerHTML+= txt3
    }
    }
        xmlhttp3.open("POST", "demo11.php", true);
        xmlhttp3.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp3.send("z=" + dbParam3);
         var txt5="";
         txt5+="<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-2 control-label'></label><div class='col-md-6'> <input type='button' value='+' onClick='add_function()' id='btnid"+i+"' /><span class='help-block'></span></div></div>"
        divtest.innerHTML+= txt5
        objTo.append(divtest);  
        }
        </script>
```

> I am trying to append this in a systematic way like country->state->city->add(+)(-)button. But i can't,it will append random way.

Screenshot attached.

In this screenshot, it show when click on add button it will append like country->state->city->add(+)(-)button but it will be append it random way, as show in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborte more on what you try to do? Do you wand to add a new input field for cities if a user clicks on the + button?

Comment: i want to append (country,state,city) in a systematic  way but it append in a rondom way

Comment: I still dont get it, could you provide some examples of how the dom should look before and after your neede funcrion and what the php script schould do!

Comment: I still dont get it, could you provide some examples of how the dom should look before and after your neede funcrion and what the php script schould do!